# firebase how to pagination for messages

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want to do pagination in chats like get last 30 new messages. And when scrolling up get more. But i don't know how to do that because my firebase structure little complex for me, Because I'm getting keys of the messages then i query to see what message it is?

Firebase structure:

```
       {
  "user_messages" : {

      "EeLIxkOEfhMUlsM8WGnHdgeT8xW2" : {

          "-KrbLjt8Eol0F36OzWGF" : "WWOdh96Yr3Qs4N3GWDVq3OlQFfB2"
    },
    "messages" : {
      "-KrbLjt8Eol0F36OzWGF" : {
        "msg" : "hello"
         [content]

      }
    }
}
```

Code:

```
messages_REF.child("user_messages").child(uid).queryOrderedByValue().queryEqual(toValue: hisUID).observe(.childAdded, with: { (snapshot) in

        let messageId = snapshot.key

        self.messages_REF.child("messages").child(messageId).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snaps) in
```

Any help, tip, hint will be appreciated.

Comment: First and foremost,  you need a value by which you will order the messages. I believe FireBase queries are ordered lexicographically by default, so you should include a timestamp with each message if you want them ordered by date. https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/lists-of-data

Comment: @Stefan thanks for your reply but i don't think that what i want, The message content have timestamp, First i observe to get message's keys and then i observe to show the message content including timestamp, But how can i do pagination to show only last 10 messages and when scrolling up show more, I don't know how to do that with "user_messages" structure

Comment: need to make use of ScrollViewDidScroll method is case to apply pagination when user scroll to a desired contentOffset make use data handler to get 20 messages then again scroll then 30 message . I hadn't implemented in swift but I had to do in my app too

Comment: @Sam Is the query you have currently returning the message properly?

Comment: @Stefan Yes i show in code how i query and works im getting the messages. But what i want how to query for last 20 and then when scroll up skip frst 20 and query for next 20 etc, i'm doing two querys first one for keys and second to view the messages. how is that gonna work

Comment: You need to specify a range of values from which you want to download messages. Message 0-20, 20-40, ect. In order to do that you need a value by which you will order them. Once you have them ordered you will use the `.queryStartingAtValue` and `.queryEndingAtValue` methods in your query to download that range. Your query will go inside the `ScrollViewDidScroll` method and you'll need to configure a multiplier so each time you reach the end you download the next set of messages.

Comment: @Stefan I thought about that but when multiplier the number of downloads it will be slower to load? Like when adding 20+ to the list each time it will be faster, any idea? i'm not sure

Comment: You wouldn't be multiplying the number of messages downloaded. You'd be multiplying the range values. So messages 1-20 first, then 20-40 and so forth. This makes downloading a bit more efficient so you aren't redownloading messages. In regards to memory efficiency, it depends on how many messages you decide to show at once and how you are displaying them.

Comment: @Stefan oh i got it now! thank you so much, But one more question what if 5 messages left in database to download, And the query downloading from 50 to 70, it will get the last 5? or it will be a crash?

Comment: The query itself will return whatever it can based on the range you set. If there's only one message, one will get returned. If there are no messages it should return nsnull.

Comment: @Stefan Alright thanks for clarification, And thank you for your time, i'll try that soon. Have a nice day